# What is the difference between using user.Email vs await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user)?

Tags: asp.net-core

What is the difference between using `user.Email` vs `await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user)`?

I mean, once I have the user instance *itself*, what is the use of the `_userManager`'s `GetEmailAsync()` method which takes exactly that user instance as parameter? I can access the user's email via its property.

I examined the source and I do understand that there is an abstraction layer of using `IUserEmailStore` but its default implementation is just returning the Email property...

I also do understand, that may exist *other implementations*, of `IUserEmailStore` but this case the question will arise: are the `user.Email` property and `_userManager.GetEmailAsync(user)` **consistent to each other, or are not?**

If not, that is a problem, if yes, then we are returned to the original question: what is the use case of using _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user)?

(the same question goes to UserName, PhoneNumber, etc properties)

Comment: There is no method named `GetUserEmailAsync` in ASP.NET Core Identity: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/search?q=GetUserEmailAsync (in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Identity/Core/src )

Comment: Please link to the documentation for the methods and types you're referring to, because I'm unable to find anything at my end.

Comment: @Dai, I am using aspnetcore-6.0.0, the UserManager class has `public virtual async Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(TUser user)` method

Comment: It's `GetEmailAsync`, not `GetUserEmailAsync` btw: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getemailasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: you are right, I sorry for your wasted time, I am editing the OP

Comment: @Dai I was aware that Identity is different thing for ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core, but unfortunately there was no tag for ASP.NET Core Identity, or I missed something. Please feel free to edit tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between using `user.Email` vs `await UserManager.GetEmailAsync(user)`?

- `user.Email` only works if your `TUser` actually has an `Email` property in the first place.

  - Fun-fact: ASP.NET-Core-Identity does not actually require whatever `class` you're using for your `TUser` to have a `String Email` property.

    - i.e. what you're presupposing (that users have e-mail addresses) **is not actually guaranteed in, nor required by, ASP.NET-Core-Identity**.
  - ASP.NET-Core-Identity's only constraint on `TUser` is `TUser : class`, so you could even use `String` or `IDictionary` for your `TUser` if you're brave enough.

    - While ASP.NET-Core-Identity *does* have a `String Email { get; }` property defined only on `class Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser<TKey>`, but you are not obligated to use this class at all: it's just a prewritten implemention that covers the most common use-cases and (probably) saves *most people* time by having them subclass it.
- *But* there are also other scenarios to consider:

  - ...such as domain-model design where users have *multiple* e-mail addresses per user, in which case having a single scalar `String Email { get; }` property simply won't work... though neither would `GetEmailAsync` either, but that's another part of ASP.NET-Core-Identity's design that you missed: you can implement `IUserStore<TUser>` and **not** implement `IUserEmailStore<TUser>`, so there wouldn't be *either* an `Email` property *nor* a `GetEmailAsync` method. (Just make sure you don't subclass `class UserStoreBase`) and instead build your store implementation from scratch.

    - In this hypothetical case, where no types implement `IUserEmailStore<TUser>`, there wouldn't be any methods *anywhere* in your codebase that would have to throw `NotImplementedException` or `NotSupportedException`. And that's a good thing: a common mantra when designing a domain-model is to "*make invalid things impossible*" (that's my corruption of the original maxim "[*make invalid state unrepresentable*](https://www.google.com/search?q=make%20invalid%20state%20unrepresentable)").
- Another scenario is some (atypical, I'll admit) system where Users *do* have an email address, but it's not stored or represented by the in-memory `User` object, in which case you would *have* to use a custom implementation of `GetEmailAsync` to get a user's email address *every time*.

  - I imagine this *might* be a possibility when using a back-end user-store with extremely fine-grained security (e.g. some paranoid Active Directory setup where the current `Thread`'s NT security token is used to attest permission to request e-mail addresses from the directory... but that idea is just speculation and I hope no-one ever actually has to support that, at least not without good blood-pressure medication on-hand).

---

In conclusion: **Not every system has user e-mail addresses, and ASP.NET Core Identity doesn't require them to expose them** - and the (admittingly *very complicated*) design of ASP.NET Core Identity reflects that.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly in that if the User _do_ have an Email property there would in reality _almost_ never be a reason to use the `GetEmailAsync` method? 

From your explanation, the only real reason I see to use that method would be if we're building a library etc. where we wouldn't know the user implementation (like the user manager it self).

Comment: @MichelJansson Not necessarily, even if `TUser` has an `Email` property, you might still want (or need) to call `GetEmailAsync` in order to refresh or reload the address, in case it changed.